# jsTree - is it possible not to use nestedSets in the DB?

Tags: jquery, jstree, nested-sets

Nested Sets are to complex for my small application, so I would like to use the Adjacency Model. My child node will know the father node and have an order nr. Is jsTree coupled to the nestedSets model, or I can use whatever I like in the backend?

Answer (score 0):

You can use what ever you want in back end.

You need to pass jsTree source data and jsTree will display it. You can pass all at once or by node using AJAX call.

Also have a look at [jsTree model back](https://github.com/deitch/jstree-model-back)